# How can I whitelist a single file in a directory in .npmignore?

Tags: node.js, npm, gitignore, package-managers, npmignore

I'm trying to make `npm` download only a single file in a directory on `npm install` of the package.

The directory looks like:

```
+- dist/
   +- 1.0.0/
   +- 1.0.1/
   +- ...lots of other dirs...
   +- file.js
```

I want npm to ignore everything but `file.js` so I tried including the following in my `.npmignore`:

```
dist/
!dist/file.js
```

Yet, npm will still download all the directories in `dist` when I install the package. I thought this was supposed to work like `.gitignore` but apparently I am missing something here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is working using glob patterns : https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package

But I would have a different approach :

```
dist/*
dist/.*
!dist/file.js
```

in order to no ignore the whole folder but it's content (the 2nd line may not be required).

Comment: This works, but honestly I still don't understand why. Why does `!dist/file.js` "kill" the `dist/` rule, but not the `dist/*` one? Will this happen in git as well?

Comment: I think `dist/` means include the whole directory as it is (there is whitelisting here), but when you say `dist/*` or `dist/.*` it means include all the files in the directory `dist`. So, it allows blacklisting I guess. At least, that is how I chose to understand it ;-)

Comment: Nice answer +1. I found the second line (`dist/.*`) was not necessary and you can test it using [how to debug npmignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412694/how-to-debug-npmignore)

Comment: `dist/.*` is used for hidden files

Answer (score 6):

**Recommendation: whitelist instead of blacklist**

Answering the use case, I would instead recommend explicitly white listing what you want to publish with the [`files` entry](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) in `package.json`, rather than blacklisting with `.npmignore`, as that makes it is much more likely that you will not accidentally publish the wrong files. See also: https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d

Here's [a concrete example package](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirodown/blob/4c15507fd5842df3645827292dc0637e14f5738b/package.json#L24) which looks a bit like:

```
{
  "files": [
    "gitignore",
    "cirodown",
    "cirodown.js",
    "cirodown.embed.min.css",
    "cirodown.local.min.css",
    "cirodown.min.css",
    "index.js",
    "main.liquid.html",
    "main.scss",
    "nodejs.js"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Why is whitelisting through package.json better than whitelisting through .npmignore?

Comment: @chpio can `.npmpignore` whitelist? I thought it blacklists only.

Comment: yeah see the question, you first blacklist every file `*` then reverse the blacklisting on the needed files through `!filename`, whitelisting them.

Comment: @chpio ah, OK, I don't know then :-) Just found now that package.json seems to support globs too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017169/npm-glob-pattern-not-matching-subdirectories Let me know if you find anything else of interest.