# npm glob pattern not matching subdirectories

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, package.json

In my `package.json`, I have a scripts block that uses `**/*Test.js` to match files. When run via `npm`, they do not match sub-directories more than one level. When executed on the command line directly, they work as expected.

Can anyone explain what is happening, and provide a workaround or solution?

#### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "immutable-ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo mocha dist/**/*Test.js",
  }
}
```

#### Execution

```
% npm run test

> immutable-ts@0.0.0 test:unit .../immutable-ts
> echo mocha dist/**/*Test.js

mocha dist/queue/QueueTest.js dist/stack/StackTest.js

% echo mocha dist/**/*Test.js

mocha dist/queue/QueueTest.js dist/stack/StackTest.js dist/tree/binary/BinaryTreeTest.js

% ls dist/**/*                                                                                                                                                                                          

dist/collections.js  dist/queue/QueueTest.js  dist/tree/binary/BinaryTree.js      dist/immutable.js.map        dist/stack/Stack.js.map             dist/tree/binary/BinaryTreeTest.js.map
dist/immutable.js    dist/stack/Stack.js      dist/tree/binary/BinaryTreeTest.js  dist/queue/Queue.js.map      dist/stack/StackTest.js.map
dist/queue/Queue.js  dist/stack/StackTest.js  dist/collections.js.map             dist/queue/QueueTest.js.map  dist/tree/binary/BinaryTree.js.map
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### Solution

Change your scripts so that what you pass to Mocha is protected from expansion by the shell:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha 'dist/**/*Test.js'",
 }
```

Note the single quotes around the parameter given to `mocha`.

#### Explanation

This issue is fixable without resorting to external tools. The root cause of your problem is that by `npm` uses `sh` as the shell that will run your script commands.

It is overwhelmingly the case that when a *nix process starts a shell it will start `sh` unless there is something telling it to do otherwise. The shell preference you set for logins does not constitute a way to "tell it otherwise". So if you have, say, `zsh` as your login shell, it does not entail that `npm` will use `zsh`.

Those implementations of `sh` that do not include any extensions beyond what `sh` should provide do not understand the `**` glob in the way you want it to. As far as I can tell, it is interpreted as `*`. However, **Mocha interprets the paths passed to it using its a JavaScript implementation of globs. So you can work around the issue by protecting your globs from being interpreted by `sh`.** Consider the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "immutable-ts",
  "scripts": {
    "bad": "mocha test/**/*a.js",
    "good": "mocha 'test/**/*a.js'",
    "shell": "echo $0"
  }
}
```

The `shell` script is just so that we can check what shell is running the script. If you run it, you should see `sh`.

Now, given the following tree:

```
test/
├── a.js
├── b.js
├── x
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── a.js
│   │   └── b.js
│   ├── a.js
│   └── b
│       └── a.js
└── y
    ├── a.js
    └── q
```

With all `a.js` and `b.js` files containing `it(__filename);`. You get the following results:

```
$ npm run bad

> immutable-ts@ bad /tmp/t2
> mocha test/**/*a.js

  - /tmp/t2/test/x/a.js
  - /tmp/t2/test/y/a.js

  0 passing (6ms)
  2 pending

$ npm run good

> immutable-ts@ good /tmp/t2
> mocha 'test/**/*a.js'

  - /tmp/t2/test/a.js
  - /tmp/t2/test/x/a.js
  - /tmp/t2/test/x/a/a.js
  - /tmp/t2/test/x/b/a.js
  - /tmp/t2/test/y/a.js

  0 passing (5ms)
  5 pending
```

Comment: This works for mocha, but not every tool I want to use it with does its own (much less the same) glob expansion.

Answer (score 4):

You can inline the `find` command with the `-name` option in your scripts to replace the extended globbing syntax provided by zsh.

In your case, the command would be:

```
mocha `find dist -type f -name '*Test.js'`
```

You can realistically omit the `-type f` part if you're confident that you won't ever put "Test.js" in a directory name.  (A safe assumption, most likely, but I included it for completeness sake)

Answer (score -1):

The glob expansion is actually done by your shell and that's why it works from the command line.

You can do `mocha --recursive` and point at your test directory.

Comment: NPM is using the shell to execute `script` commands. What is the difference in shell execution environments? And no, I cannot use `-recursive`, because I don't have a test folder. As the `ls` listing shows, the tests are adjacent their implementations.