# npm messes up glob path expansion when running scripts

Tags: npm, glob

When running `npm test`, which is defined by:

```
"test": "mocha test/**/*.spec.js"
```

The path expansion fails to match scripts at a depth of more than one. Therefore everything in `test/lib/*.spec.js` gets matched, but a test at `test/lib/subdir/*.spec.js` does not.

When I run `mocha test/**/*.spec.js`, however, all the tests are matched and run. I'm at something of a loss as to how to debug this.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure this is due to `npm` running scripts in `sh` instead of my shell (`zsh`). I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34522827/79247 .