# How to debug .npmignore?

Tags: npm, npmignore

**How can package files** (these to be published) **be listed to debug records in `.npmignore`?**

I'm looking for something like equivalent of `git ls-files` for `.gitignore`.

The only way I have found so far is to pack the package and then list the archive which I find a bit clumsy:

```
npm pack
tar -tzf <package-id>.tgz
```

Comment: a workaround you already hinted at: assign .gitignore the content of .npmignore, hit git ls-files, revert .gitignore after you have the data you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41412694/how-to-debug-npmignore#comment70029216_41412694) the fact that `.npmignore` and `.gitignore` use the same syntax can be leveraged:

```
git ls-files -co --exclude-per-directory=.npmignore
```

The command above lists exactly files that are not npm-ignored according to `.npmignore` file. (On top of that npm automatically ignores some other entries like `node_modules`.)

Git [`ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) command generally lists combinations of files in working directory and index.

- `-c` option says show cached files
- `-o` show 'other', i.e. untracked files
- `--exclude-per-directory=.npmignore` use `.npmignore` as name of files of ignore entries

---

**EDIT:**
Since the approach above has bunch of [exceptions](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) - files that will never or always included regardless of content of the `.npmignore` - I find it unreliable. Following command is heavyweight but reliable:

```
file_name=$(npm pack) && tar -ztf $file_name && rm $file_name
```

It packages the project, lists package files and at the end removes created package.

Answer (score 12):

`npm pack --dry-run` prints out what will be included

```
logger ❯ npm pack --dry-run
npm notice
npm notice   @supercollider.js/logger@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 817B  package.json
npm notice 199B  README.md
npm notice 1.7kB lib/index.d.ts
npm notice 693B  lib/index.d.ts.map
npm notice 3.9kB lib/index.js
npm notice 2.9kB lib/index.js.map
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          @supercollider.js/logger
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice filename:      supercollider.js-logger-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  3.0 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 10.2 kB
npm notice shasum:        6c60400e1d61723ce3d7705bb3a8a9a907b7d83b
npm notice integrity:     sha512-+1tQZMPQr3cAp[...]zPu6R/BqYdIJQ==
npm notice total files:   6
npm notice
supercollider.js-logger-1.0.0.tgz
```